# DFS: confused by visiting, visited and un-visited

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, depth-first-search

In the following codes from [Leetcode discussions](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/35515/share-my-25-line-dfs-20-line-bfs-and-clean-union-find-java-solutions).

```
public class Solution {
    public boolean validTree(int n, int[][] edges) {
        int[] visited = new int[n];
        List<List<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0; i<n; ++i) { adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); }
        for (int[] edge: edges) {
            adjList.get(edge[0]).add(edge[1]);
            adjList.get(edge[1]).add(edge[0]);
        }
        if (hasCycle(-1, 0, visited, adjList)) { return false; }  // has cycle
        for (int v: visited) { if (v == 0) { return false; } }  // not 1 single connected component
        return true;
    }

    private boolean hasCycle(int pred, int vertex, int[] visited, List<List<Integer>> adjList) {
        visited[vertex] = 1;  // current vertex is being visited
        for (Integer succ: adjList.get(vertex)) {  // successors of current vertex
            if (succ != pred) {  // exclude current vertex's predecessor
                if (visited[succ] == 1) { return true; }  // ###back edge/loop detected!
                else if (visited[succ] == 0) {
                    if (hasCycle(vertex, succ, visited, adjList)) { return true; }
                }
            }
        }
        visited[vertex] = 2;
        return false;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1, As for `if (visited[succ] == 1) { return true; }  // back edge/loop detected!` in DFS, I tried `visited[succ] == 1` and `visited[succ] >= 1`, all of them work. **I am confused what is the difference between ``visited[succ] == 1`and`visited[succ] ==2```?** Can they detect different types of circles?

2, It seems that if we use `visited` to store True and False (visited and un-visited), it still works (from another [Leetcode topic](https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/77932/python-solution-with-detailed-explanation)). **When should we use un-visited, visiting, visited? and When should we use un-visited, and visited? Any examples?**

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switching to `visited[succ] >= 1` does not yield an equivalent algorithm: the current algorithm will detect Directed Acyclic Graphs (DAGs), while the modified algorithm will detect only trees (all trees are DAGs, but not all DAGs are trees).

The algorithm uses `2` to allow DAG detection. If all you need is tree detection, you can switch to using Booleans; with DAGs, however, simply marking a vertex visited is no longer sufficient. Consider this simple graph:

[image: DAG]

If you leave `visited["C"]` at `1`, the algorithm would report a cycle when it tries the A -> C edge.

Comment: Thanks. for undirected graph, we should use `visited[succ] == 1` to detect circles. But for directed graph, we should use `visited[succ] ==1` for DAG and use `visited[succ] == 2` for trees? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @BAE If you are detecting a tree, you should use `visited[succ] != 0` to cover both `1` and `2`.